# Determining if a stored procedure exists anywhere?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

This is an Oracle question.

I need to write a pl/sql function that is given a name and determines if that corresponds to any stored procedure anywhere that is callable. That is, the name could be any of these forms:

somename  -- could be a procedure in the current schema or a synonym for a procedure elsewhere
firstpart.secondpart - could mean package firstpart (in current schema OR a synonym) with proc secondpart in it OR it could mean user firstpart and procedure secondpart
first.second.third - presumably means user first, package second, procedure third

(I think those are all the possibilities.)

I could go through each of the possibilities one by one, looking in all_synonyms and all_procedures, but is there a better way that let's Oracle do most of the work? i.e. attempting to call the procedure and catching the exception if it doesn't exist? Unfortunately, I noticed that calling a procedure (via a begin;end block in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) returns the same error, -6550, when I tried the name of a procedure that doesn't exist (in a package that does) as when I tried a valid procedure with the wrong arguments.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest trying to call the procedure because then all the side effects of the procedure would occur if the call succeeds.  Better IMHO to query the metadata.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: After writing a procedure that tries many of the possibilities and realizing that I could never really find all of them, I realized that if I know what arguments the procedure is supposed to have, I can merely use dbms_sql.parse with a begin/end block that calls the procedure and if it's not a valid procedure call, dbms_sql.parse will throw an exception which I can trap.  I will have to be careful to avoid sql injection problems though.